# What is @Action in Wordpress?

Tags: plugins, php, functions, shortcode, actions

I have found this code snippet on a plugin.

```
/** * @Action(name="workforce_content_loop_before", priority=10) */

public static function show_breadcrumb() {
        echo do_shortcode( '[workforce_breadcrumb]' );
    }
```

This comment code is use to add an action instead of add_action function (here show_beradcrumb action). But how this is working inside comment. I am asking here because I didn't find any documentation in wordpress.

[image: Screenshot here]

Comment: It's not "working" inside a comment. It won't do anything. It's just a comment. It's likely intended to indicate where the function is hooked, and seems to be written in such a way to allow a tool to assist or document it in some way, but I'm not familiar with the format. You would need to ask the plugin author about its purpose, since this is not something from WordPress.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But when I remove the comment, the function below under it, not showing on page. That means somehow the comment is for a reason.

Comment: You will have to ask the plugin developer. That means they are doing something highly unorthodox. This is not normal WordPress behaviour.

Comment: Is this a public plugin you could link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is called php annotations. Many of them are built-in via a standard called phpdoc (like @var), and they are used by the interpreter or the static tools (also by humans for a more structured comment).

There is another usecase for these annotations, and it's to run some code - probably using reflections (which usually is last resort, since it's slower), here is an example from a different system which I'm using: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-annotations/en/1.13/custom.html

For example in old versions of TYPO3 you could use @inject this way.

Comment: Thanks Romand. But is @Action is also a PHP annotation or it is created by Wordpress? Besides, can I create custom annotation?

Comment: As far as I know there is no built-in functionality in WP. It's a "feature" of PHP language that you can write by hand, as I gave the example in the link. You can create custom annotations, again, as said in the link, using reflections. However - if you can do it in any other way, then do it in a different way - as I said, using reflections should be last resort.